# Normalize a wavefunction

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, quantum-mechanics

This is a little beginner level, but how do we normalize $\Psi(x)= x(a-x)$ over the interval $0\leq x\leq a$. I do not understand how separate the a from the equation.

Comment: over the interval 0<=x=<a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you have some parameter $a>0$ and a function
\begin{align*}
\psi:[0,a]&\to\mathbb R\\
x&\mapsto x(a-x)
\end{align*}
which should be the wave function of some quantum system. For this, however, it has to be normalized which is why you are looking for $C=C(a)>0$ such that the modified function $\Psi(x):=\frac1C\psi(x)$ satisfies $\int_0^a|\Psi(x)|^2\,dx=1$, that is,
\begin{align*}
1=\int_0^a|\Psi(x)|^2\,dx&=\frac1{C^2}\int_0^a|\psi(x)|^2\,dx\\
&=\frac1{C^2}\int_0^ax^2(a-x)^2\,dx\\
&=\frac1{C^2}\Big[ \frac{a^2x^3}3-\frac{ax^4}2+\frac{x^5}5 \Big]_0^a=\frac1{C^2}\frac{a^5}{30}\,.
\end{align*}
Now this is equivalent to $C^2=\frac{a^5}{30}$ or $C=\sqrt{\frac{a^5}{30}}$.
Therefore the normalized wave function is given by
\begin{align*}
\Psi:[0,a]&\to\mathbb R\\
x&\mapsto \sqrt{\frac{30}{a^5}}x(a-x)\,.
\end{align*}